# HTML/CSS - responsive background doesn't work only on Android - Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

My responsive background works well on PC Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera. It works as well in Firefox on Android. But in Chrome on Android I'm getting something like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix it? I want it to be fullscreen on Android Chrome too. I've tried everything...

CSS and HTML code:

```css
.background {
    background-image: url("images/bgsky2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="background">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported meny years ago !

See this link will help :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301

And i remember this code helped me :

```
    html{
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
}
body{
 min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: It didn't change anything :( still the same situation.

Comment: Yep, I tried min-height: 100% and max-height:100%, nothing changes.